# Zig std.log.info not printing anything with cross-compiled to AARCH64 binary

Tags: zig

I have copied a hello world Zig program and it runs fine locally on my Mac:

```
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() anyerror!void {
    // Note that info level log messages are by default printed only in Debug
    // and ReleaseSafe build modes.
    std.log.info("All your codebase are belong to us.", .{});
}

test "basic test" {
    try std.testing.expectEqual(10, 3 + 7);
}
```

I then cross-compiled it to ARM:

```
zig build-exe src/main.zig -O ReleaseSmall --strip -target aarch64-linux
```

Seems to compile the right thing:

```
$ file ./main
./main: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, stripped
```

Then I copied it to my Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu 22.

It also shows the file is recognized and runs without error, but it just doesn't print anything. I tried redirecting both stdout and stderr to a file but nothing comes out.

What can be the problem?

Comment: i am using Zig 0.10 I've just now downloaded from the Downloads page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add, `std.log.info` [does not display in ReleaseFast or ReleaseSmall builds by default](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/47c4d4450281bfddebf89cbad4f9c1fdcc7b0b65/lib/std/log.zig#L103-L108). You can change this by overriding the log level in your main zig file:

```
pub const log_level: std.log.Level = .info;
```

Or, you can print to stdout directly rather than using logging functions:

```
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() !void {
    const stdout = std.io.getStdOut().writer();
    try stdout.print("Hello, world!\n", .{});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the code I had copied was not the "real" hello world. It only prints to the console when it's built in debug mode.

The production-grade hello world in Zig is this:

```
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() !void {
    const stdout = std.io.getStdOut().writer();
    try stdout.print("Hello, {s}!\n", .{"world"});
}
```

Compiling this the same way, it works both on Mac and when compiled to aarch64-linux and executed on my Raspberry Pi.